# Делать сайты еще актуально?

Tags: php, python, веб-сайт

Создание сайтов еще не умирает ?
Почему вообще есть спрос на сайты ?
Актуально ли будет в будущем такой профиль?

Comment: Смешные вопросы

Comment: Не, неактуально, сейчас маски надо делать, в будущем будет актуально))))

Comment: Конечно, актуально. Даже очень. Что за странный вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

это было и будет актуально. Но лучше всего выделяться среди других, и тогда всё пойдёт - поедет. Но этот вопрос не очень для stack overflow, советую посмотреть фриланс сайты, и анализировать рынок.